# Cannot login to Magento front end using username

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am having issues trying to log in to Magento front end after updating from 1.3 to 1.7.0.2. Everything seems to be working fine and all my data has been imported successfully. When I try to login to the front end using the username, it fails and returns an invalid login or password. If I try to login using the email address, it works as should! I have tried the following [FIX](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/197191/), but I'm still having no luck. Has anyone else experienced this or know how to fix this problem?

Many Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the frontend login is reserved to customers (and customers don't have a "username"), in the Magento version 1.7 the customer authentication is performed using the customer email, as you can see in *app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php*

```
 public function authenticate($login, $password)
    {
        $this->loadByEmail($login);
...
```

So, if you don't want to override this method, there is no way to login in the frontend using an username.

Comment: Thank you so much for this information! After comparing the file from 1.3.2 and my latest, it looks like there was edits to the core code! I am now going to make an override for this and store it in app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php

Comment: You're welcome, anyway overriding the core functionality in app/code/local/Mage is a bad practice. I suggest to override this public function extending the Mage_Customer_Model_Customer in a separated module.

Answer (score 0):

I did experience this. Try to login through some other browser such as Mozilla firefox and do the following settings as mentioned below for Google Chrome. I recently had the same problem and simple trick worked for me. Also this is for people who cannot access the dashboard on **Google Chrome**. If you can please carry on by working on Mozilla Firefox because I guess this issue is not persistent on Mozilla firefox.

So the solution for chrome is:

Goto **System->Configuration->Web**. Expand the **Unsecure and Secure** tab. Change the Base URL to `http://127.0.0.1/[Your folder name]` if your using localhost or change it to your Site URL through which you are accessing the frontend. I had to **login twice** to get the Dashboard since when I entered the details for the first time, it just refreshes and comes back to the same page as you mentioned it as looping. Please try and let me know whether it worked for you too. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to login, it was because the field "Associate to Website" was not set to the correct website.